# How to send my program to background while a certain process is running

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, wait

I have a program that starts another program (iexplore.exe), then my program should go "invisible" or atlast to background, and stay there while this asd.exe is running. This code is working, BUT it eats memory, and sometimes its just stays hiden while asd.exe is not running anymore. There must be a more efficient way to do this =)
So my program code :

```
   this.Hide();
   Process.Start(Path.Combine(Path, "iexplore.exe")); 
   Process[] Running_ = null;
   do
   { // this loops eats memory!
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
      Running_ = null;
      Running_ = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
   }while (Running_.Length > 0);
   this.Show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use the Process.Exited event here, prevents blocking the UI thread and avoids hassling threads.  Like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var prc = new Process();
        prc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        prc.Exited += processExited;
        prc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
        prc.Start();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void processExited(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            this.Show();
            this.BringToFront();
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Never used the Exited event. Definitely great if it works as advertised!

Answer (score 3):

What about the Process.WaitForExit method?

```
this.Hide();
Process p = Process.Start(Path.Combine(WoWPath, "asd.exe"));
p.WaitForExit();
this.Show();
```

Comment: Blocking the UI thread is not legal.  Very unhealthy to the window manager.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just wanted to show a much simpler way to achieve the same (and even a less buggy) result than the code from galaris. If I would use this, I would execute it in an own thread and not in the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

I like what MatthiasG has done, but WaitForExit() is a blocking call...Your program will be hidden until asd.exe finishes executing, but your program will not be doing anything productive.

This may be the desired result.  If not, I would

1. Hide the form -> `this.Hide();`
2. Create a thread (BackgroundWorker will suffice)... In the DoWork() event, create the Process object for asd (as MatthiasG had done):

   ```
   Process p = Process.Start(Path.Combine(WoWPath, "asd.exe"));
   p.WaitForExit();
   ```
3. In the RunWorkerCompleted event, have `this.Show();`

Comment: I agree. Using a BackgroundWorker (or a new thread) is indispensable when using the Process.WaitForExit method or any other thread blocking operation.

Comment: Thank you for this soulution, but I think Hans Passant gave a more efficient method. Thank for the help anyway.

Comment: To me they are two different ways of doing it.  What Hans has shown is that the Process class has a built in Event called Exited.  That works and when it is raised you can do whatever you want.  My solution called upon a separate thread to do the exact same thing, with its own Event.  Both of them used events.  It's really all about how you want the solution done.  Hans' solution might look cleaner and it is definitely something new that I learned!

Answer (score 1):

- No need to null WoWRunning_. Process.GetProcessesByName changes the reference anyways
- Call .Dispose() !

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Dispose()` on each object in your array, then it stops to eat memory.

I mean instead of `WoWRunning_ = null;` put there something like `foreach(Process p in WoWRunning_) p.Dispose();`

But anyway your algorithm should be revised completely, it is quite expensive because you load an array of all processes again and again.

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to deal with these things.