# Detect end of running process without Admin rights

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible to detect when a certain process gets killed or closed the normal way. With other words if the process is removed from the process list.

I know it's possible by using WMI and the System.Management.ManagentEventWatcher, however this needs Administrator rights, I'd prefer if it's done without requiring those.

Since at the moment I use Process.Start("ProgramX.exe"); I'd like to find out when that program is closed or terminated. So that I can act upon that.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send my program to background while a certain process is running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584932/how-to-send-my-program-to-background-while-a-certain-process-is-running)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as i don't send the program launching the other program to background..

Comment: So i'm not allowed to say thanks in advanced for the help? Sorry but that sounds plainly rude to me, and I will keep on putting that regardless, sue me for being nice..

Comment: Also regarding the duplicate, I was wondering if I should use (for example) use the Process.WaitForExit Method provided by Pop Catalin, or if I should use System.Management>MangementEventWatcher. I've done more than enough Googling to find out whether this has been properly dealt with, no reasons where given on the matter as far as i could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the process yourself then you can wait for it to finish using [Process.WaitForExit method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx). Note that waiting is a blocking operations and it's best if you do in in another thread, then signal the event from that thread.

Ex:

```
var process = Process.Start("ProgramX.exe");
...
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though would you use the WMI or Process.WaitForExit Method? I did a poll and users don't really care whether some (trusted) program requires admin rights or not.